# How to parse this nested JSON array in android-Kotlin-Recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I'm getting json parse from API and trying to use it on recyclerview adapter. I couldn't.

I'm using retrofit-gson

I'm experiencing problems with the "a" and "b" on the retrofit how to define the series.

MY JSON

```
{

    "sampleobject": {
        "a": [
            {
                "sampletitle1": "..",
                "sampletitle2": {
                    "test1": 1,
                    "test2": ".."
                },
                "b": [
                    {
                        "sampletitle3": "value",
                        "sampletitle4": "value",
                        "sampletitle5": {
                            ..
                        },


                    }
                ],


            },

        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: If you own the backend, then you shouldn't have dynamic keys. Then it'll be easier to automate the parsing.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have. Do you have a chance to show examples?

Comment: Try using Gson library, you can convert the JSON text to Map. see this example here https://makeinjava.com/serialize-convert-map-object-tofrom-json-java-gson-example/